# Which browsers support the html 5 <audio> tag on Windows today?

Tags: html

Which browsers support the html 5 `<audio>` tag on Windows today?

Edit: Trying http://moztw.org/demo/audioplayer/ as a test.  Chrome 2, and Safari 4 not working for me.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure why people are voting to close, knowing which browsers to target is definitely programming related.

Comment: You could have used back-ticks to make the <audio> as code, or else used html entities.  The editor allows HTML formatting.  Not SO's fault you don't know how it works.

Comment: To be clear, I'm trying to find one that works with http://moztw.org/demo/audioplayer/

Comment: The wiki article I linked to below lists some newer browsers as "partial" support for the audio tag. You'd have to test and see what "partial" means exactly. :)

Comment: Mr Shiny and New, it works in the title, it works in the <comments> so yeah, its SO's fault.

Comment: The problem with this question is dat it outdates..

Comment: @borisCallens And now all the answers are not up-to-date anymore :-(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Safari 3.1+ and Firefox 3.5 both support the audio element. Opera 10 does *not* support the audio element though it does support an older version of it in the form of an Audio object. Chrome 3 will likely support the audio element.

(Just saw you wanted to know support for that specific page. That mostly depends on the codecs you are using I'm afraid.)

(Disclaimer: I work for Opera and am a member of the HTML WG.)

Comment: Cheers.  However, I tried safari 4 on the Moz page and it doesn't seem to work.  If you have time, could you please confirm?

Comment: As I suspected the reason is codecs. Safari uses QuickTime which by default does not support the Ogg/Theora/Vorbis codecs Firefox 3.5 does ship with. You will need to install http://www.xiph.org/quicktime/download.html and then it should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: They cited this answer in this article, nice job :) http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Comment: so again we are back to plugins with safari /facepalm

Answer (score 28):

if this evaluates to true:

```
!!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType
```

, then you have audio tag support in your browser. Doing a feature detect like this is a lot better than parsing userAgent strings.

Alternatively, you can use something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) to handle this detect and many others for you.

Comment: Other ideas/tools for detecting support: Dive into HTML5 reference http://diveintohtml5.org/everything.html jPlayer http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/HTML5.Audio.Support/

Comment: Paul, but on my device your javascript code returned true but still the audio tag doesn't work "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; GT-S5282 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30" screen shot:

Comment: screen shot: https://s.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/b628d455967b460f8fa55e78699ba492_A.jpeg?a=answers&mr=0&x=1477409252&s=a5d53bb0b52cfdf441397bd3d4716d94

Answer (score 10):

Our blog [post](http://www.scirra.com/blog/44/on-html5-audio-formats-aac-and-ogg).

Contains more up to date information on modern browser support for HTML5 audio.

**As of July 2011**

**IE9**

Supports MP3 and AAC

**Firefox 5**

Supports Ogg and Wav

**Chrome 12**

Supports Ogg, MP3, Wav and AAC

**Safari 5**

Supports MP3, AAC and WAV

**Opera 11**

Supports Ogg and Wav

As you can see from the data above and from reading the blog post, it's a bit of a frustrating situation as there isn't one audio format supported by all browsers.  There's no immediate sign of any resolution yet either.

Answer (score 7):

I put together a [list of when the browsers](http://helephant.com/2011/12/29/the-html5-audio-tag/#browser-support) started supporting the audio tag and which audio formats they support.

The support is pretty good now. Since IE9, the latest versions of all the desktop browsers and most the mobile browsers support the audio tag. The only reason not to use it, would be to support old versions of IE, but you can always provide a fallback if that's important.

Here are the details for desktop browsers:

```
+---------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Browser | Supported since version |             Formats              |
+---------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| IE      | 9.0                     | AAC or .mp3                      |
| Firefox | 3.5                     | .ogg, .wav                       |
| Chrome  | 3                       | .mp3, .ogg                       |
| Safari  | 4                       | Any audio supported by Quicktime |
| Opera   | 9.5                     | .ogg, .wav                       |
+---------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Here are the details for mobile browsers (no format information, sorry):

```
+--------------+-------------------------+
|   Browser    | Supported since version |
+--------------+-------------------------+
| iOS Safari   | 4                       |
| Opera mobile | 10                      |
| Opera mini   | no support (Dec 2011)   |
| Android      | 2.3                     |
| Blackberry   | 6                       |
+--------------+-------------------------+
```

If you want to use the audio, it's [important to provide both .ogg and .mp3 versions of the file](http://helephant.com/2011/12/29/the-html5-audio-tag/#supporting-different-browsers) to get good cross browser support.

```
<audio controls>
   <source src="/my-podcast.mp3" />
   <source src="/my-podcast.ogg" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)) article comparing each browser's HTML5 support:

Comment: That fooled me as well, since there is no mention of versions in that article.  Besides, I'm hearing alot about html 5 <video> support these days, so either that page is wrong, or its out of date?

Comment: Probably best not to make decisions based on Wikipedia articles. try Modenizr instead http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 2):

For Safari to support audio on Windows, Quicktime needs to be installed. The javascript snippet reports correctly if it's supported or not.

Answer (score 1):

All of these browsers support the functionality of the  tag.  The reason your player does not work on Safari is because you are using OGG files.  OGG is supported on Firefox and Chrome.
Firefox supports only WAV and OGG.
Chrome supports everything.
Opera supports only WAV.
Safari supports everything but OGG.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

opera 10 and ff 3.5 , don't know about safari

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure of Safari 4, Firefox 3.5 from RC1 and maybe Chrome 2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it is supported either partially or fully in the gecko, webkit and presto engines.

So any browser which uses an up to date version of those engines should support it.

Answer (score 0):

Gecko, Webkit and Presto engines are suppose to support it, but I think only partly. So Firefox 3.5 and Opera are your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

The page (moztw.org/demo/audioplayer) works OK in Chrome 3 (dev channel)