# Playing sound file doesn't work in all browser except IE

Tags: javascript, wav, audio

I have This line

```
<EMBED NAME=""mySound"" SRC=""DocID2858_voice-message.wav"" LOOP=FALSE AUTOSTART=True HIDDEN=TRUE MASTERSOUND>
```

It works for ie but doesn't work for rest of browser.
is there any way to make that.

Comment: Oh dear... There's a special place in hell for mark-up like that. Anyway, try combining this with the <audio> tag, every other browser should support it.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp

Comment: Use flash, with 99% market penetration, and much nicer user interfaces, flash is going to be a lot easier for your users.

Comment: not all modern browsers support <audio>, and there is no agreement on a single codec either.  You're probably stuck with flash for now.  See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007223/which-browsers-support-the-html-5-audio-tag-on-windows-today

Comment: Using "AUTOSTART=True" makes people cry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using IE 8, Firefox 3.5 and higher, Safari 4, Google Chrome, then you'll be aware that these browsers support HTML 5.

For HTML 5 use the `<audio></audio>` tag. More information can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp).

Comment: Those browsers support *some things* that have come out of HTML5; there is no HTML5 standard to ‘support’ fully yet. IE8 doesn't support `<audio>` and the other browsers (lamentably) disagree on what formats to support.

Answer (score 0):

```
SRC=""DocID2858_voice-message.wav""
```

You've doubled your quotes. I'm amazed if this still works in IE!

If you must use an `<embed>` tag, the syntax would be:

```
<embed id="mysound" src="DocID2858_voice-message.wav" type="audio/wav" loop="false" autostart="true" hidden="true">
```

The `type` attribute is necessary to prevent an unnecessary double-fetch in IE. `mastersound` was a Netscape 4 nonsense supported by nothing today. `loop` and `autostart` are not universally supported. `autostart` is universally hated.

Anyhow I'd strongly recommend against using `<embed>` these days. Or even the more up-to-date `<object>` way of embedding a media player. Embedded media players are fragile. They're often user-hostile or unreliable or just not present at all. Today, most authors use a Flash player to play back MP3 instead. (It's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857037/flash-based-wav-player) to play back WAV, but it's not very nice.)

Tomorrow, HTML5 `<audio>` elements will be used instead. It is possible to use `<audio>` with fallback to Flash today, but this will mean having more than one audio format on the server.