# What are the best practices for on-demand sound?

Tags: javascript, html

Recently we've been developing some sort of a web based IM application and I would like to ask the best way to implement message alert tones preferably controllable via JavaScript. Are there any existing libraries we can use for this?

Comment: Until HTML5 the most reliable was FLASH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [html5 audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) , the benefit is that you are not using any additional plugins (quickTime, flash...), but the [browser must support the audio tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007223/which-browsers-support-the-html-5-audio-tag-on-windows-today)

```
function SoundPlay (src)
{
    var soundEmbed = document.createElement("audio");
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("src", src);
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("autoplay", 'autoplay');
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("type", 'audio/mpeg');    

    //jQuery can help you with the removal of the audio element
    $(soundEmbed).one('ended', function(evt)
    {
        $(evt.target).remove();
    });

    // or, if you are not using jQuery
    soundEmbed.onended = function()
    {
        document.body.removeChild(soundEmbed);
    };

    document.body.appendChild(soundEmbed);
}
```