# DOCTYPE tag in IE 9

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog, media-player

In my web application I am using media player object in a jquery dialog.

When using DOCTYPE   code i cant see the media player.Actually there is media player.While right click on that area , i will get corresponding menu.I can even see tooltip.But just the object is hidden ( cant see ) .

If i removed the DOCTYPE  tag, then all things works as i expected. Any idea about this?

This only happens in **IE 9**

The code is shown below:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1"><title>
    Test 
    </title>
       <link href="jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script src="jquery_1_4_4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {



    $("#player").dialog();
 });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="player">
test

    <object id='mPlayerCallTranscription' classid='CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-

00C04F79FAA6'
                                    type='application/x-oleobject' height="42" width="250">
                                    <param name='AllowHideDisplay' value='True' />
                                    <param name='AllowHideControls' value='True' />
                                    <param name='URL' value="sdsd" />
                                    <param name='AutoStart' value='false' />
                                    <param name='balance' value='0' />
                                    <param name='enabled' value='True' />
                                    <param name='fullScreen' value='False' />
                                    <param name='playCount' value='1' />
                                    <param name='volume' value='100' />
                                    <param name='rate' value='1' />
                                    <param name='StretchToFit' value='True' />
                                    <param name='enabledContextMenu' value='True' />
                                    <param name='MovieWindowSize' value='0' />
                                    <param name='DisplayMode' value='0' />
                                    <param name='ShowControls' value='True' />
                                    <param name='ShowDisplay' value='False' />
                                    <param name='windowlessVideo' value='True' />
                                    <param name='uiMode' value='full' />
                                    <%--   !IE--%>
                                    <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="asds" width="251" 

id="mPlayerCallTranscriptionMozilla"
                                        height="42">
                                        <param name="src" value="sds" />
                                        <param name="autostart" value="false" />
                                        <param name="controller" value="true" />
                                        <param name="ShowControls" value="true" />
                                        <param name="BufferingTime" value="2" />
                                        <param name="fullScreen" value="false" />
                                        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true" />
                                        <param name="AutoSize" value="false" />
                                        <param name="InvokeURLs" value="false" />
                                    </object>
                                </object>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If i removed the doctype , ie ,

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

, i can see the player .But all alignment  is gone.

Here i am attaching pics of both cases

1.While not using DOCTYPE

[image]

2.While using DOCTYPE

[image]

**EDIT:**

If i am not using jquery dilog ,its works fine .

Comment: Why are you using a *frameset* Doctype? Why aren't you using [`<audio>`](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/)?

Comment: @Quentin, We are not using HTML 5 . Is there anything wrong with DOCTYPE?

Comment: — You don't have a frameset document.

Comment: @Quentin `<audio>` isn't supported by IE8- and the kind of audio it supports varies per browser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007223/which-browsers-support-the-html-5-audio-tag-on-windows-today/6792525#6792525 But the Frameset Doctype is plain wrong. :)

Comment: That was my mistake while typing the question .I have updated my question

Comment: In IE9 document mode, jQuery versions older than 1.5.1 don't work. Make sure you use the latest stable versions of jQuery and all plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find out the problem .The problem was with `jquery.ui.all.css`  .

There is a sub css file named `jquery.ui.dialog.css` in the above css

and i changed the below line of code

```
.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
```

to

```
.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; }
```

Now its works fine

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using XHTML 1.0 Strict (if you don't want to use HTML5) instead of Transitional. That forces browser to standards mode instead of quirks mode (which could be the case with IE9):

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype forces browsers to use standards mode (or almost standards mode, but never quirks mode). https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla%27s_DOCTYPE_sniffing

Comment: That's true. And actually it seems that opposite is happening on the original poster - when doctype is removed, things work.