# What is the current file support for <audio>?

Tags: html, audio, browser

I'm trying to figure out which audio files are compatible with the <audio> tags across all the browsers. I've seen sites that state that some use .mp3, and some use .ogg, but somewhere else I saw that all supported .wav. But those sites were outdated.

Is there any up-to-date information on the current support for <audio> for *all* browsers across *all* platforms?

Comment: Close duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007223/which-browsers-support-the-html-5-audio-tag-on-windows-today

Comment: Yes, but that's 3 years old, and I'm looking for specific file types.

Comment: An answer there has an answer as of July 2011

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@animusion is wrong, Internet Explorer 9 *does* support the audio tag!

You only need two formats to cover all browsers today:

**Ogg Vorbis** (often .ogg): covers all browsers except IE and Safari, presumably because they hate the internet and don't want to support free formats.

**AAC** (often .m4a): covers Internet Explorer and Safari.

[You should *not* use MP3.](http://www.scirra.com/blog/64/why-you-shouldnt-use-mp3-in-your-html5-games)

Comment: I didn't test the AAC file because I don't have an AAC file. IE didn't support any of the other files, including the M4A.

Answer (score 0):

This resource is pretty up to date : http://www.scirra.com/blog/44/on-html5-audio-formats-aac-and-ogg. Even MS has a new article on media tags, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781023.aspx

Comment: Thank you! Didn't see that in the other question until Paolo brought it up.