# JavaScript, playing sound effect in onmouseover event

Tags: javascript, audio, playback, onmouseover

I suppose its a common question, but none of the tutorials and post I've seen have helped me so far. What I want its a sound to play whenever the cursor is over a menu image which is also a link. There's already another instruction in the onmouseover event for the image to flicker, but I've read that the event can have multiple instructions. Here's the code
(sorry if it looks messy)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var sonido=document.getElementById("neonclip");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="neonclip">
   <source src="http://www.eleyte.net/portafolio/neon.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 130px;">
<a href="pagelink"> 
<img onmouseover="this.src='img2';
sonido.play(document.getElementById('neonclip'))
onmouseout="this.src='img1'"src="img1"/> </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I did this following an example but it didn't work. I know it'll have problems in firefox because it doesnt support mp3 format, but thats another story. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just user below two format to play sound in all browsers.

```
<audio preload id="neonclip">
  <source src="sounds/dingdong/57718^DingDong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="sounds/dingdong/dingdong.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

And to play the sound try this

```
<a href="pagelink"> 
<img onmouseover="this.src='img2'; document.getElementById('neonclip').play()" onmouseout="this.src='img1'"src="img1"/> </a>
```

Comment: still won't play in IE, i haven't tried in Firefox because I'm still waiting for the file in the correct format. But, as I said, on Internet Explorer, no sound and no error. And in firebug the only error that prompts its that the file format is "Specified "type" attribute of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://www.eleyte.net/portafolio/neon.mp3 failed" which is logical as mp3 is not compatible

Comment: but in firefox "ogg" format is supported and IE doesn't support audio tag.

Comment: then its not useful, I need an all-browsers solution... and last time I checked IE supported Audio tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp

Comment: IE9 : Supports MP3 and AAC. so just add another format of Mp3 also.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007223/which-browsers-support-the-html-5-audio-tag-on-windows-today

Comment: don´t get it, if IE supports MP3 and Audio Tag and this is MP3 and Audio tag, then the problem is not support-related, right?

Comment: Ok! Right know with .ogg it works on firefox, but not on IE, do I need to add a conditional sentence perhaps?

Comment: Yes you need third source tag of Mp3 for IE (IE9 only).